# Returning coordinates via AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm trying to return value via AJAX. Below is the code that I put together based on some examples I found and it seems to work, but I think there's a better way of doing it?

```
(async () => {
    const url = new URL("/ajax-page", window.location.origin);
            
    const headers = new Headers([
        [
            "Content-Type",
            "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
        ]
    ]);

    const body = new URLSearchParams([
        ["sl", slug]
    ]);
    
    const res = await fetch(url, {
        method: "POST",
        headers,
        body
    });
                        
    if (res.ok) {                                
        let mkr = await res.text();
            crd = mkr.split("|");  
            lat = crd[0],
            lon = crd[1];

          console.log(lat+' '+lon);
    }
})();
```

**PHP (ajax-page)**

```
// php magic gets values
echo  $mar['lat'].'|'.$mar['lon'];
```

Do I even need to use *(async () => {...})();* anymore?

Comment: change php side to `echo json_encode($mar);` then `let mkr = await res.text();`, into `const {lat, lng} = await res.json();`, much better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These lines:

```
lat = crd[0],
lon = crd[1];
```

are not variable declarations (because there's no `let` keyword). It's using the comma operator, so it's equivalent to:

```
lat = (crd[0], lon = crd[1])
```

The comma operator returns the value of the second expression, so both `lat` and `lon` are being set to `crd[1]`.

The cause of this problem is that you ended the previous two lines with `;` rather than `,`. The whole declaration should be:

```
        let mkr = await res.text(),
            crd = mkr.split("|"),
            lat = crd[0],
            lon = crd[1];
```

If you use your IDE's auto-indent feature it would have shown that this isn't grouped the way you intended.

Answer (score 0):

*await* can be used only inside an *async* function. You cannot avoid it. Asynchronous functions implicitly return a promise, so other async functins can *await* their results.